# Options to remove buttons by profile from Listviews

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, list-view

I found the following idea related to removing buttons from list views by profile here:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Kp1MAAS

I'm using LEX and from what I'm aware, the only options would be the following:

1. remove profile access to the object where the list view reside (this
   isn't a solution I can use because the profiles that don't need
   access to the buttons still need access to the object)
2. write code that controls what profiles have access to the
   functionality behind the button (this also isn't a solution I can
   use because the requirement is to remove visibility to the buttons
   by profile. They do not want to see the buttons for certain
   profiles.)
3. finally, overwrite the list view page with a custom visualforce page
   and completely write custom code (I know this was possible in
   classic using a URL hack, but I'm not sure if this is possible in
   LEX any longer. Also, it would be a significant lift)

Are these the only options? Any other solutions that someone may be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to restrict button visibility on listviews other than what you already mentioned.

There is an idea for this marked as in development and should be released in Winter 21
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br37AAC